# Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: '2015-03-08 02:00:44.031' for column 'TimestampUtc'

Tags: mysql

So I read a few other questions on this topic, but don't understand this problem.
This update fails:

```
UPDATE `logentry` SET `TimestampUtc`='2015-03-08 02:00:44.031' WHERE `LogEntryId`='5';
```

But this update works

```
UPDATE `logentry` SET `TimestampUtc`='2015-03-08 03:00:44.031' WHERE `LogEntryId`='5';
```

The only difference being the hour value changed from 02 to 03.

The column is Timestamp(3)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "The column is Timestamp(3)", please explain.

Comment: The time giving you an error does not exist in your time zone because of Daylight Saving Time. In your time zone, time went from 01:59:59 to 03:00:00 on 2015-03-08. "MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval."

Comment: @ikegami  UTC doesn't have DST.

 "UTC does not change with a change of seasons, but local time or civil time may change if a time zone jurisdiction observes daylight saving time or summer time. For example, UTC is 5 hours ahead of local time on the east coast of the United States during winter, but 4 hours ahead during summer."

Comment: @greg_diesel, I know. The only thing that means his connection's time zone isn't UTC, which isn't surprising.

Comment: @DavidSoussan   timestamp(3) has 3 decimal places for fractional seconds